# Android: WebView with hardware acceleration show only white screen

Tags: android, android-webview, hardware-acceleration

I notice that loading a page with huge javascript content like JQuery on a `WebView` cause very slow performance in Android 3.x. I have searched and found that setting `android:hardwareAccelerated` to true would be better.

However, after doing this, the webview only show white screen, nothing.
Following is what I use to test:

```
public class TestWebViewWithHAActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");        
}
```

and set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` at application level in manifest

Some of log show render error:

```
07-10 17:30:44.847 D/libEGL  (2417): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-10 17:30:44.857 D/libEGL  (2417): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_VIVANTE.so
07-10 17:30:44.877 D/libEGL  (2417): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_VIVANTE.so
07-10 17:30:44.907 D/libEGL  (2417): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_VIVANTE.so
07-10 17:30:44.947 I/        (2417): visual ID: 1
07-10 17:30:44.947 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): Creating OpenGL renderer caches
07-10 17:30:44.947 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 17:30:44.947 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): Layers will be composited as regions
07-10 17:30:45.067 I/ActivityManager(121): Displayed com.example.testwebviewwithha/.TestWebViewWithHAActivity: +705ms
07-10 17:30:45.567 I/dalvikvm-heap(202): Clamp target GC heap from 48.338MB to 48.000MB
07-10 17:30:45.587 D/dalvikvm(202): GC_EXPLICIT freed 219K, 4% free 47342K/48839K, paused 3ms+5ms
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): could not compile shader 35632:
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): (1:0) : warning : Extension : GL_OES_EGL_image_external is not provided by this compiler.
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): (2:0) : error : Extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external do not support 'require'.
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): (2:0) : error : Error in parsing.
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): (8:0) : error : syntax error
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): 
07-10 17:30:46.447 D/ShaderProgram(2417): couldn't load the pixel shader!
07-10 17:30:46.457 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.467 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.487 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.517 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.527 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.537 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.557 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.577 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.607 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.617 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.647 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.657 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.677 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.687 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.707 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.737 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.747 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.767 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.777 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.807 D/GLUtils (2417): GL ERROR - after glBindTexture() glError (0x501)
07-10 17:30:46.817 D/OpenGLRenderer(2417): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
07-10 17:30:46.837 D/GLUtils (2417): GL ERROR - after glBindTexture() glError (0x501)
07-10 17:30:46.837 D/GLUtils (2417): GL ERROR - after drawQuad() glError (0x501)
```

What is the reason causing this?

Of course, if I don't use hardware accerleration, it work fine. But it would contradict my purpose.

I have also tested on emulator of Android 3.0 device. I work fine but I doubt the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` really take effect or not.
Is it just my device cannot support? I am using Ainol Novo 7 Basic tablet(Android 3.2).

Comment: is there internet permission in your manifest file??

Comment: did you add a transparent background to your webview somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, the activity is all the code I used

Answer (score 2):

Add a check like this in you activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```